# unable to import from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy

Tags: python, python-module

Am getting a module not found error - from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy.  the log below you can see that import bitcoinrpc is ok.  am I missing something or did authproxy move or ?? thx

```
PS C:\python38> cd c:\python39
PS C:\python39> python
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python39\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\Python39', 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
>>> from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitcoinrpc.authproxy'
>>> import bitcoinrpc
>>>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use dir on bitcoinrpc to see if it has authproxy? maybe there's a problem with your install

Comment: thx.  bitcoinrpc doesn't have those objects.   the correct module is python-bitcoinrpc.   install and usage works fine.  appreciate your input